# Making proportional vimeo iframe

Tags: html, css

I'm making my first steps learning to code. I've been taken some courses on Internet and now Idecided to continue learning from the experience while I build a Wordpress child theme by myself.

The thing is that I'm using a vimeo iframe in one template.

```css
iframe {

 width:70%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/41845276" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I like it, it works fine, but I would like to can resize it proportionally and doesn't have a lot of black space around it. To try to always have something like this

[image]

and not like this:

[image]

For example I see it like this in my iphone and it's not so good because it takes almost all my screen:

[image]

Do you have some suggestion?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if you know the real proportion of the video like `16:9` or `4:3` you can use the viewport units to set the size. Like this:

> 16 : 9  
>  70vw x 39vw

```css
iframe {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:70vw;
  height:39vw;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/41845276" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DaniP . Can I ask you how you can make the conversion from the proportions to the viewport units?

Comment: @ValentinVerdegales it's a [Simple Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication) ... so if you know `70vw` equals `16` then `9` will be `(70x9)/16`.

Answer (score 0):

What I regularly do is to load the thumb or preview image in an image tag, which I can position behind the video. So the outer div orietates to the proportions of the preview image, which should be the proportions of the video. The video gets width and height 100%. This way the proportions should always match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the iframe in a div and give it a padding-top of the aspect ratio. You could either use the CSS calc function or precalculate it (56.25%).

HTML

```
<div class="embed embed-16-9">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/41845276" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.embed {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.embed--16-9 {
  padding-top: calc(100% / (16 / 9));
}

.embed iframe {
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```